# Saving 10000's of row in bridge table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have five tables Agent, AgentAddress , Address , ContactInfo and AgentContactInfo.
Here AgentAddress and AgentContactInfo are bridge table.

I have to Import 10000's of row from excel and save.
What is the best approach to save the file
Now I am using following code but getting exception for large data:

```cs
var transaction await_context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
try
{
    foreach (var item in getExcelData)
    {
        var countryId = await _context.Country.Where(x => x.CountryName == "Nepal").Select(y => y.CountryId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        Entities.Agent.Agent newAgents = new()
        {
            CountryId = countryId,
            AgentOfficeName = item.Name,
            Branch = item.Branch,
            ContactPerson = item.ContactPerson,
            InsertPersonId = personId,
            InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };
        await _context.Agent.AddAsync(newAgents);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var addressTypeListItemId = _context.ListItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ListItemSystemName == "Permanent").ListItemId;
        Address newAddress = new Address
        {
            AddressTypeListItemId = addressTypeListItemId,
            City = item.City,
            State = item.State,
            District = item.District,
            StreetName = item.Address,
            InsertPersonId = personId,
            InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };
        await _context.Address.AddAsync(newAddress);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        AgentAddress agentAddress = new AgentAddress
        {
            AgentId = newAgents.AgentId,
            AddressId = newAddress.AddressId,
            InsertPersonId = personId,
            InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };
        await _context.AgentAddress.AddAsync(agentAddress);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var contactTypePhoneId = await _context.ListItem.Where(x => x.ListItemSystemName == "PhoneNumber").Select(y => y.ListItemId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        ContactInfo phoneNumbers = new ContactInfo
        {
            ContactNumber = item.Telephone,
            ContactTypeListItemId = contactTypePhoneId,
            InsertPersonId = personId,
            InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };
        await _context.ContactInfo.AddAsync(phoneNumbers);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        await _context.AgentContactInfo.AddAsync(new AgentContactInfo
        {
            AgentId = newAgents.AgentId,
            ContactInfoId = phoneNumbers.ContactInfoId,
            InsertPersonId = personId,
            InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

```
My Entities:
    public class Agent : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string AgentOfficeName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? OpenedDate { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Country))]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ListItem))]
        public int? AgentTypeListItemId { get; set; }
        public ListItem ListItem { get; set; }

    }


[Index(nameof(AgentId), nameof(AddressId), IsUnique = true)]
    public class AgentAddress : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgentAddressId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Agent))]
        public int AgentId { get; set; }
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Address))]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Entities.Address.Address Address { get; set; }
    }

[Index(nameof(AgentId), nameof(ContactInfoId), IsUnique = true)]
    public class AgentContactInfo : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgentContactInfoId { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Agent))]
        public int AgentId { get; set; }
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ContactInfo))]
        public int ContactInfoId { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the exception?

Comment: Quick thought... Have you tried calling _context.SaveChanges only once at the bottom the for loop?

Comment: You might want to `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` in batches, and clear the change tracker. Otherwise you'd need to use a bulk insert / table value parameter to pass a large amount of data directly to the database.

Comment: First, don't use an ORM for ETL. Different jobs, different tools. Second, the code is causing the problem. Don't call `SaveChanges` all the time, not even in batches. A DbContext is a Unit of Work and `SaveChanges` commits all cached changes. Needless to say, executing the changes one by one is a *lot* slower than executing them all at once. EF Core [already batches all changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating#batching) but can be configured to use a specific batch size

Comment: Including the exception message you are seeing will make it much easier for people to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Version**

*Remove* all attempts to save, commit or manually control transactions and just call `SaveChangesAsync` at the end.

Don't try to retrieve primary keys one by one. EF Core will take care of creating the relations and fixing up foreign keys. Just create valid objects and let EF Core figure out the insertion order.

Don't load lookup data inside the loop either. That just wastes time loading the exact same data multiple times.

In the common [Blog and Posts example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) used by most tutorials, you only need to create a Blog with some Posts, and EF Core will take care of insertions and primary keys:

```
using(var ctx=new SomeContext())
{
    var blog=new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" }
    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "Hello World", Content = "I wrote an app using EF Core!" });
    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "Second Post", Content = "..." });

    blog.Blogs.Add(blog);

    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Explanation**

Normally, an ORM shouldn't be used for ETL jobs like data loading. There are no entities in a data loading job, or rather the entities are Row, Column and Transformation, not Address and Name.

10K rows is very little data though and EF Core can easily handle this if used *properly*. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work that tracks all changes. Those changes are committed when `SaveChanges` is called **only once at the end of the work**. There's no reason to use an explicit transaction because `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally.

Furthermore [EF Core already batches all changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating#batching) but can be configured to use a specific batch size.

This means that all you need to do is *remove* code. Simply creating the DbContext, adding the classes and calling `SaveChangesAsync` at the end is enough to insert data in batches, in a single transaction:

```
using(var context = new MyContext(...))
{
     var countryId = await context.Country
                                   .Where(x => x.CountryName == "Nepal")
                                   .Select(y => y.CountryId)
                                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    
     foreach (var item in getExcelData)
     {
         var newAgents = new Agent()
               {
                    AgentOfficeName = item.Name,
                    ...
                    InsertPersonId = personId,
                    InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                };
        var newAddress = new Address
                {
                    AddressTypeListItemId = addressTypeListItemId,
                    City = item.City,
                    ...
                    InsertPersonId = personId,
                    InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                };
         var agentAddress = new AgentAddress
                {
                    Address = newAddress
                    InsertPersonId = personId,
                    InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                };     
         agent.Addresses.Add(agentAddress);

         context.Agents.Add(newAgent);
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The call `context.Agents.Add(newAgent);` will add `newAgent` and *all* related objects to the DbContext in the `Added` state. When `SaveChanges` is called, EF Core will insert them in the proper order. First all child entities in batches, retrieving their PKs. Then it will fix up the parent entities and insert all of them in batches.

EF Core won't just INSERT one row after the other either, it will use an `INSERT ... OUTPUT inserted.ID` with multiple value rows to insert multiple objects *and* return their IDs in the same query.

Comment: First of I'd like to thank you @PanagiotisKanavos for helping me.
And I'd also want  you to know that I'm a beginner here..

Can you please tell me What is **agent** here in `agent.Addresses.Add(agentAddress)`

And I guess I can do similar for my contact table.
Actually I tried first but not getting Id's in bridge tables.
Again Thank you.